# What is the best way to approach a professor for "formal" guidance/advisorship when they have no proficiency in the topic?

Tags: thesis, advisor, medicine

My situation is as follows: I have studied and completed a maths degree from a very prestigious and competitive university. I have then worked a few years as a mathematician and have then decided to change fields and become a doctor (physician). Now I'm getting to a point where I have to create (another) masters thesis.

I'm planning to create and publish something, which most likely none of the professors at my medical university (which is a lower tier, non technical one in terms of research) know or understand anything about and would like to turn this in as a masters thesis.

My university allows this (counting a published paper as a master thesis), however I'm not sure how to approach a professor in a non intimidating/threatening way and in such a way that they will be ready to "sign with their name".

Their support is purely formal, i.e. they only need to sign their name since my work will be checked by the editors of the journal, however the amount of professors that are at the university is very limited, and as such I'm trying to figure out the best way to go about this.

What is the smartest way to go about all of this?

Comment: Ask one of the professors you know how to go about this. Perhaps they will just sign on. It's probably better to do this when the work is (mostly) done, so they know it's a real project and not just your hope or fantasy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The issue I'm most worried about is, if somebody decides not to sign on, I'm afraid the others might decide also not so sign on simply because the other professor didn't. Should this happen then I'm stuck with no advisor at all (and thus the thesis can not be submitted). The work is mostly done. I have yet to submit the paper to the journal but I'm fairly certain it will be accepted and published.